# facebook, LiveId and googlemail login in own application c#.net

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, google-openid, windows-live

I have a project in which my client wants to login using facebook, gmail or Live Id account.
I am just new to OAuth concept.
Some idea but not in deep.
I have few queries, can anyone please help me out.

1. What the internal mechanisum, i need to do with my DB.

   i.e. when facebook redirect to my application successfully, do i need to save return details from facebook to my application and then use it like a normal user who is login using my site login page.

[link for my question 1, please answer me for only 2nd query.](http://youhack.me/2011/06/15/integrate-login-system-with-yahoo-connect-using-oauth/)

I assume this, because of above link.

Some of the OAuth, like LIveId not not redirect back to local port.
    i.e. it is not accepting localhost:123/mysite/myredirectpage.aspx. 
of course it is accepting www.myliveurl.com/myredirectpage.aspx.
Then how can i test the whole things in my local development environment.